# Get seconds until end of day in PHP

Tags: php

In PHP, how can I get the number of seconds until the end of day?

Thanks.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

First thought:

```
86400 - date('H') * 3600 - date('i') * 60 - date('s')
```

Faster version derived from VolkerK's answer:

```
strtotime('tomorrow') - time()
```

Comment: Second method is technically better as well as being faster. Not all days have 86400 seconds. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7780464/is-time-guaranteed-to-be-leap-second-aware

Comment: ...and a more practical reason why 86400 isn't quite good enough: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2411564/march-14th-not-86400-seconds-long

Answer (score 8):

```
$rs = strtotime('24:00') - time();
echo $rs;
```

edit: even faster

```
echo mktime(24,0,0) - time();
```

Comment: Doesn't work, but `$rs = strtotime('23:59:59') - time() + 1; echo $rs;` does. :)

Answer (score 7):

If you're using [Carbon](http://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/#api-difference) you can simply use

`Carbon::now()->secondsUntilEndOfDay();`

Answer (score 1):

Here you go! You can specify the timezone too:

```
    $timezone = new DateTimeZone( 'Asia/Kolkata' );

    $today = new DateTime('now', $timezone);
    $tomorrow = new DateTime('tomorrow', $timezone);
    $secondsLeftInTheDay = $tomorrow->getTimestamp() - $today->getTimestamp();

    echo $secondsLeftInTheDay;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$sDate = '2014-12-01 23:59:58';
$oDatetime1 = new DateTime($sDate);
$oDatetime2 = new DateTime($sDate);

$oDatetime1->modify( 'tomorrow' );

echo $oDatetime1->getTimestamp() - $oDatetime2->getTimestamp();
```