# Is time() guaranteed to be leap-second aware?

Tags: php, linux, windows, time, hhvm

PHP manual states that `time()` returns ["](http://php.net/manual/en/function.time.php)the current UNIX timestamp[" ﻿<sup>ᴀ</sup> ­](http://php.net/manual/en/function.time.php)and `microtime()` returns the ["](http://php.net/manual/en/function.microtime.php)current Unix timestamp with microseconds[" ﻿<sup>ʙ</sup>](http://php.net/manual/en/function.microtime.php).

However, are these functions **guaranteed** to behave like [that of  strictly conforming POSIX.1 systems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time#Leap_seconds)?

Specifically, do leap seconds  get inserted  in such   a way that the output  of `time()` | ­`microtime()`   jump **backwards** by 1 second at the start of the next day, (which is the also at the end of the leap second,) giving us **repeated** return values —as opposed to *fresh* unique values— throughout the entirety of the first second of that next day?

For example, if we poll `time()` | ­`microtime()` every microsecond throughout the span of  1998﻿-12﻿-31 and 1999﻿-01﻿-01, would there be two occurences of each value  within the range 915 ﻿148 ﻿800 ＜﻿＝ x ＜ 915 ﻿148 ﻿801?

Comment: How many seconds have you spent on this?

Comment: @Ash: cute but informative... haha

Comment: @Ash do you mean SI seconds or solar seconds?

Comment: PHP gets the time from the system it runs on, so I suppose this will depend on the operating system.

Comment: Check this post from Google, they figured a great way to do it: http://googleblog.blogspot.com/2011/09/time-technology-and-leaping-seconds.html

Answer (score 11, accepted):

PHP is a serverside language. The time() function will resolve to the system time of that server. If the server is running an NTP daemon then it will be leap second aware and adjust accordingly. PHP has no knowledge of this, but the system does.

Answer (score 13):

The UNIX timestamp, as you get it from time() in PHP, is a peculiar beast.

It took me a long time to understand this, but what happens is that the timestamp increases during the leap second, and when the leap second is over, the timestamp (but not the UTC!) jumps back one second.

This has some important implications:

- You can always accurately convert from UTC to a UNIX timestamp
- You can *not* always (for all points in time) convert from timestamp to UTC
- Unix timestamp is non-contiguous, i.e. it steps back. (Or alternatively, it stays the same without incrementing for 2 seconds.)
- If you get a conversion error converting from UNIX timestamp to UTC, the error will be at most 2 seconds off. (This means you could get the wrong day though.)
- In *retrospect*, the Unix timestamp will appear linear. This means that if you are storing time series data and you are not concerned with a single second or two per year being incorrectly represented, then you can consider stored timestamped data contiguous.

**Workarounds**

What if the Unix timestamp neither jumped backed abruptly nor stayed the same for 2 seconds? This is exactly what Google has made happen for their servers. Their solution was to [slowly skew the time merely milliseconds at a time](http://googleblog.blogspot.se/2011/09/time-technology-and-leaping-seconds.html) over a long period of time, to make the leap second shift virtually invisibly to applications. (As far as the applications and operating systems on Google servers are concerned, leap seconds are no longer inserted by [the IERS](http://www.iers.org).)

Comment: @Prof., Would Angelom's answer be more accurate though? That it's dependent on the platform?

Comment: @Pacerier, not exactly the *platform* but PHP depends on the time on the operating system to be correctly configured.

Answer (score 1):

`time()` just returns the UNIX-Timestamp. This means, that it is not affected by leap seconds (and such), because you will never "lose" time, just because someone decided it. Only textual representations (e.g. created using `date()`) are affected.

Comment: I guess the question should be; is date() leap second aware?

Comment: @King Am I misunderstanding something, because UNIX time is affected by leap seconds: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time

Comment: It's true that the Unix timestamp is not aware of leap seconds, but that also means that textual representations of the timestamp cannot be aware of them either, since there is no way to distinguish between the leap second and the second before/after it.

Comment: @Pacerier The Wikipedia article says the exact opposite: "...defined as the number of seconds elapsed since midnight Coordinated Universal Time (UTC) of January 1, 1970, *not counting leap seconds*."

Comment: @Juhana: Sounds a little bit crazy, but it seems Pacerier is right... Must say, didn't know that. However, in your argumentation it would be impossible to convert an ISO- to an UNIX-timestamp, but the other way round would always be possible, because every UNIX-timestamp second is unique.

Comment: @Juhana: "When a leap second is inserted (which has occurred on average once every year and a half), the Unix time number increases continuously during the leap second, during which time it is more than 86 400 s since the start of the current day, __and then jumps down by 1 at the end of the leap second__, which is the start of the next day."

Comment: Ok, I see we might have different definitions for the word "affect".