# Does REALTIME clock support leap seconds?

Tags: c, system-clock, unix-timestamp

I have a call like `clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME)`, does it handle leap seconds? If not, what changes are required? Working on Solaris.

Comment: Also http://stackoverflow.com/a/12086110/193892 might be of value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your Unix system is synchronized with NTP, chances are that it handles leap seconds.

See this article for more information: [NTP Leap Second](http://www.meinberg.de/english/info/leap-second.htm#os).

Comment: you mean, if NTP is up and running it handles leap seconds and we dont have to do anything extra for it?

Comment: "If your Unix system is synchronized with NTP" how to check it?